# Recovering an account after losing access to OpenID provider

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I used to be fairly active on Stack Overflow a few years ago using [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54157/rafl). I have since let the domain I used as an OpenID provider lapse and someone else purchased it.

Is there a way for me to recover that other account, and ideally merge this account into the other?

I'd be happy to provide evidence of me being who I say I am. One method I thought of could be to make an upload to the [CPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN) account that's linked from the other profile.

Comment: Have you already tried the contact form, like the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) suggests?

Comment: If your CPAN commits are signed with a public **PGP key** that can be linked to your older profile, this could be a way of proving your identity.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I did after you suggested it and was able to get my accounts merged that way (without providing any additional information to verify my identity, scarily)